# Can I use server running on PHP to communicate with my Android application?

Tags: php, android

I'm planning to make a website in PHP. At some point in future I might need to create an Android application for my website. Now I know that Android is Java based, so my question is will I be able to communicate with my application i.e. sending and receiving data from my server on which my PHP website is running and how?

Comment: A common approach people have adapted to now days is 'API-First' development.
http://www.api-first.com/
Based around building a data structure, irrespective of the device or interface

Comment: Yes, it's very common to have PHP server side scripts that return JSON to a native Android app, which can be parsed in the Java code.  There are many tutorials that you can reference which will get you started should you want to go that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to generate JSON objects using your php scripts then using JSON parser in your android app to use those objects.
Using this you easily send and receive data without having to change php scripts. You can also follow this link :

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: can I send and receive images by this approach?

Comment: No it can not be used for images. For that you need to implement HttpClient.

Comment: you can send image to server using given link: http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Comment: I think that is good for getting a basic understanding, but the documentation in that tutorial is severely outdated. I'd recommend on reading up on mysqli_connect instead of the mysql commands found in that tutorial.